# Glassfish custom default app not working on Firefox

Tags: jsf, glassfish, jsf-2.2, glassfish-4.1

For my app to be available from *mydomain.com*  instead of having to add the `contextPath` like this: *mydomain.com/myapp/*  I set the default web module as my app under the

> Configurations >> server-config >> Virtual servers >> server

It works perfect in all browsers except for `Firefox`, here the default page is still showing:

> GlassFish Server Your server is now running
>
> To replace this page, overwrite the file index.html in the document
>   root folder of this server. The document root folder for this server
>   is the docroot subdirectory of this server's domain directory.
>
> To manage a server on the local host with the default administration
>   port, go to the Administration Console.

I'm using GlassFish 4.1 and deploying a JSF 2.2 web app

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you clear cache?

Comment: @Geinmachi, that did it,  Wow very dumb thing, I hadn't thought of that, should I erase the question ?

Comment: No erasing questions violates rules which is taken into consideration by the system. You can instead answer your own question and mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that  @Geinmachi was right, even though its weird since I only have firefox and some other browsers for testing purposes, I had never placed the domain url there but  clearing the cache did the trick. Thank you @Geinmachi